# Shapefile layer cannot be generated - blank warning

Tags: qgis, shapefile, installation, qgis-3

Installed QGIS 3.0 (w/Python 3.6.5) to replace v2.X.
Started a new project - imported shapefiles and everything looks good.

Problem: Click "Create New Shapefile Layer" and I get the pulldown menu (file name, geomeotry type, etc.) Fill everything out and click "ok"
I get this:

> Layer creation failed. Please check message log for further information.

Message log says this:

> 2018-04-13T09:04:34 Warning:

That's it. Warning is blank.
Under the OGR tab I've got:

> 2018-04-13T09:04:34    WARNING Creation of OGR data source SG sites.shp failed: Failed to create file SG sites.shp: Permission denied.

Why is my permission being denied.  Tried a full reinstall but results are the same.

Comment: which directory are you trying to write to? do you by some chance not have permission to write there?

Comment: Try without whitespace in the name

Answer (score 1):

Thanks - problem solved.
It was a problem with admin priv. Had another user on this machine yesterday and the permissions had been changed. Switched to 'admin' and now it works as expected.

Cheers!